# Replacing a double quotes qualifier of data using sed or awk or perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have txt file with `|` delimiter and `"` qualifier. I would like to change the qualifier to `~` symbol, problem which I have is actual column value text have double quotes.

I need to change the qualifier without removing the double quotes within the column values. I have provided the sample one record:

```
"Live Your Dreams: Be You"|"20 Feb 2018"|"2 formats and editions"|"Are you being swept away by life being busy? Are things seemingly out of your control? Do you want to calm the chaos in your life? Are you ready to transform your life? In 
"Live Your Dreams"
now AMAZON BESTSELLER, readers are shown how to take immediate control of their mental, emotional, physical and entrepreneurial destiny."|"All this and more as you immerse yourself in the story that opens up like scenes from "a Bollywood movie""|"Indian Edition"
```

I have already tried with `sed` and `awk` by referring the content in stack overflow and unix.com, but double quotes inside the column is creating issues.

Desired Output:

```
~Live Your Dreams: Be You~|~20 Feb 2018~|~2 formats and editions~|~Are you being swept away by life being busy? Are things seemingly out of your control? Do you want to calm the chaos in your life? Are you ready to transform your life? In 
"Live Your Dreams"
now AMAZON BESTSELLER, readers are shown how to take immediate control of their mental, emotional, physical and entrepreneurial destiny.~|~All this and more as you immerse yourself in the story that opens up like scenes from "a Bollywood movie"~|~Indian Edition~
```

Code Tried:
sed 's_"([^*])"_~\1~_g' data.txt > tdata.txt

Results as per the above sed:

```
"Live Your Dreams: Be You~|~20 Feb 2018~|~2 formats and editions~|~Are you being swept away by life being busy? Are things seemingly out of your control? Do you want to calm the chaos in your life? Are you ready to transform your life? In 
"Live Your Dreams"
now AMAZON BESTSELLER, readers are shown how to take immediate control of their mental, emotional, physical and entrepreneurial destiny.~|~All this and more as you immerse yourself in the story that opens up like scenes from "a Bollywood movie"~|~Indian Edition~
```

Any help with `awk` or `sed` or `Perl` script would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Prabhu

Comment: Hello, please always try to show us the code you've tried. We can help you make it work or suggest different solutions. Questions with no research effort are generally frowned upon here. Also, take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I have added the expected output and tried code, thank you guys!

Comment: Yeah I was able to do that, but record starting and ending are still having double quotes. If you notice closely, that column value have a string in a separate line with double quotes. So if I change the double quotes value of start and end of the record, that string also changing. that is my problem

Comment: Your input format is ambiguous. How do you know where a record ends?

Comment: I dont know the end of records in my file, thats the tricky part!

Comment: That's not "tricky", that's just unsolvable.

Comment: 1. do you know how many fields per record you have? 2. can you fix the process that creates the output to generate well-formed CSV (i.e. properly escape the interior quotes)?

Comment: Do your lines end with `\r\n` and the mid-field "newlines" are actually just `\n`s alone, as would be output by Windows tools like Excel? Do `cat -v` on your file and look for `^M`s to represent `\r`s if you aren't sure. When you have a file containing multiple records, only providing 1 record for sample input is of limited use - provide at least 2 records and show/tell us what characters separate the records.

Comment: @melpomene you are absolutely correct, it is unsolvable. I tried to find a solution for this issue over the last one completed week and ended up with nothing.

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah we know how many records will be there in the file, but still we cant process it based on that record count as column size varies depending upon the user input.

Comment: @EdMorton No, lines are not ending with \r\n, it is just ending with /n. Actual file is not generated out of windows tools,  using a simple java code to export the data.

Comment: As I was not able to find the solution for this issue, I am left with no option other than changing the qualifier. So I have requested my client changed it to a non-keyboard special character (like delta). In this case, I am able to escape the double qoutes using simple sed command and load the data to Data Warehouse. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What you should be asking is for the client to send you well-formed CSV. They need to properly escape the quotes so you can parse the file. It doesn't matter what the quoting character is, it needs to be properly escaped

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have is mal-formed CSV data, where the separator char is `|`.

It is malformed because the "interior" quotes are not escaped: In a CSV field that contains quotes, the quotes should be duplicated, like this

```
1,2,"field,with,commas","this field ""contains quotes"" that are duplicated"
# ..................................^^...............^^
```

If it possible to fix your input data to look like this:

```
"Live Your Dreams: Be You"|"20 Feb 2018"|"2 formats and editions"|"Are you being swept away by life being busy? Are things seemingly out of your control? Do you want to calm the chaos in your life? Are you ready to transform your life? In 
""Live Your Dreams""
now AMAZON BESTSELLER, readers are shown how to take immediate control of their mental, emotional, physical and entrepreneurial destiny."|"All this and more as you immerse yourself in the story that opens up like scenes from ""a Bollywood movie"""|"Indian Edition"
```

where the interior quotes on lines 2 and 3 are properly escaped, then you can use a CSV parser to transform the output quotations. Perl's csv parser can handle fields containing newlines:

```
perl -MText::CSV -e '
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", shift(@ARGV);
    my $csv_in = Text::CSV->new({ quote_char => "\"", sep_char => "|", binary => 1 });
    my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new({ quote_char => "~", escape_char => "~", sep => "|", binary => 1 });
    while (my $row = $csv_in->getline($fh)) {
        $csv_out->say(STDOUT, $row);
    }
    $csv_in->eof or $csv_in->error_diag();
' file.csv
```

```
~Live Your Dreams: Be You~|~20 Feb 2018~|~2 formats and editions~|~Are you being swept away by life being busy? Are things seemingly out of your control? Do you want to calm the chaos in your life? Are you ready to transform your life? In 
"Live Your Dreams"
now AMAZON BESTSELLER, readers are shown how to take immediate control of their mental, emotional, physical and entrepreneurial destiny.~|~All this and more as you immerse yourself in the story that opens up like scenes from "a Bollywood movie"~|~Indian Edition~
```

Comment: I have tried this approach of escaping the double quotes inside the column value, it is not working for all scenarios. Consider the double quotes string present at the end of column, in such case, while escaping the string's double quotes, I am facing issue with double quotes not detecting as it is present just before the qualifier.

Comment: Did you end up with 3 double quotes before the pipe?

Comment: No whenever it encounters the double quotes at the end of the column value, script is considering that already escapes (|"BookStore processing "Validation ""|) as it is present along with qualifier

Comment: To be parsed as CSV, you **must** be given `|"BookStore processing ""validation"""|`

Answer (score -1):

In Perl you can try this one liner:

```
perl -anF'\|' -E 'for (@F) {s/^"/~/;s/"$/~/} print join "|", @F' file.txt
```

This will split each line on `|` then substitute a `"` at the beginning or end of each field with a `~`.

According to new information in the comments: If you want to leave lines with a single column (field) unchanged:

```
perl -anF'\|' -E 'if (@F == 1) {print; next} for (@F) {s/^"/~/;s/"$/~/} print join "|", @F' file.txt
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, double quotes in the column value(line 2 in the data) is also changing when I tried with this perl script

Comment: Sorry I cannot see what you are referring to. Can you be more specific, what double quote exactly is the problem?

Comment: |"..."Live Your Dreams"..."| is string present in the column 4, when we run data through the perl script. 
The above string is converted like this |~...~Live Your Dreams~...~| thats a problem

Comment: Ok, so this is for the new data.. Is there supposed to be two lines of data or one line. From your question, there seems to be a new line starting after `"Live Your Dreams"`? I can think of a reason you got the problem is that you split what should be one line, into three parts? I suggest you reduce the length of the lines in your question, so it will be easier to avoid this type of problems

Comment: Actually consider that column as comments or reviews from User. so single column value will extend to multiple lines just like the sample record which I showed. this is where I am facing the issue. Unfortunately, I can not change the data, so I have to process this way. Any advice on this?

Comment: Ok, so if there is only a single column it should not be changed? So we just leave it alone, but if there is more than one column on a line we do the substitutions?

Comment: Let say we have a single column with multi-line records with double quotes jute like the show sample record, I am not suppose to change the data in anyway. In this scenario, what you would suggest? Could you clarify on the substitution part?

Comment: Problem here is that, if double quotes inside the values are changed to the qualifier ~ symbol, as you already know, I would face issue in ETL processing like loading or any kind of processing.

Comment: Just to clarify, can a column contain a newline character? I think this might be the part where I am confused :)

Comment: Yes Hakon, it can contain newline character

Comment: Ok, then I missed that part. I will have to propose a new solution to you.. First, how do you then know the end of a line? That is, how many columns will there be on a line. Is it predetermined or do you check for something special, like a `"` followed by a new line character?

Comment: Answer is we can't judge the end of line. For each line, columns count may vary depending on the column value size. For one file, columns are fixed But still it may vary from file to file. We can not check for " followed by the new line character, because in one column we have multi-line records with double quotes and newline characters.

Comment: @Prabhu Then your problem has no solution. You simply don't know where each record ends or where your column boundaries are within a record.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Perl script which you provided second seems working, let me check with different files and confirm in an hour! Many thanks for your support!

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am still confused with how you skipped the double quotes within the values, could you please explain the second perl statement?

Comment: For the second Perl statement (actually it is better to call it a command which consists of some statements), I just check the number of fields `if (@F == 1)`. If the number of fields equal to one, we do no substitutions. Instead we simply print the line as we read it.. If you need more explanation, please let me know

Comment: @melpomene My requirement was like that and files are auto generated, so I don't have an option except to find the solution. 
To clarify on your statement,  you are correct I don't know the column boundaries within the column or ending of the record in terms of file processing. If file processing is not possible, then I have to think In terms of data, as number of columns are fixed, I believe I could with Text:CSV_XS processing in perl!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you for the explanation, I got it. But if we have more than one multi-line column values with double quotes, then this solution will not work, Kindly correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you for your support, I will mark this answer as correct after confirming with multiple data loads. Thanks again!

Comment: @HåkonHægland as you said it is not working if double quoted values are present in more than one column, thanks for you help!